# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException while ImageIO.read in NetBeans?

Tags: java, image-processing, netbeans, indexoutofboundsexception

I have been trying to read a image in netbeans using `ImageIO.read` .. 
This is the code below ..

```
try{
     buffimg = ImageIO.read(new File(getClass().getResource("output.png").toURI()));
} catch(Exception e){
     out.println(e);
}
```

I run the code and the following exception is thrown .. What shoud i do ? Is this a bug ?

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: what is `buffimg` in your sample code? what is the size of `buffimg`?

Comment: The buffimg is just a instance of BufferedImage .. As follows ..                    BufferedImage buffimg;  buffimg = null;

Comment: Where's the stack trace? :-) It's hard to diagnose the problem further without knowing which classes/methods are involved.

Answer (score 0):

The `getCode()` method of ImageIO reader does not check the return value of read() method of ImageInputStream and uses it in offset calculation.
However, method read can return -1 to indicate EOF. We shuld check this return value and throw IOException if end of file is reached